# balebot not working with using ngrok

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, bots, messenger

I use ngrok to test the balebot on the local network. But error 502 occurs in network connection.
ngrok listens to 8000 port

```
Config.base_url = "https://RANDOM.ngrok.io/"
```

error:

```
aiohttp.client_exceptions.WSServerHandshakeError: 502, message='Invalid response status'
```